# how to get the Ajax value in a Rails Controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I managed to send a string (test) value using Ajax call , but I can't really display it within my view , using my Controller (flash notice or whatever) :

**the Ajax call using JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#completed").live('click', function() {
        alert (document.getElementById('query').value); 
});

$.ajax

({ 
    url: '.',
    data: {
    chosenformat : "myvalue",
    },
    type: 'post',
    success: function()
    {
        alert ('success'); 
    }
    }); 
});
```

**I want to get the 'chosenformat' value within my Controller :**

```
format = params[:chosenformat]
flash[:format] = "chosen format: " + params[:chosenformat].to_s()

if !(format.nil?)
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # contact.html.erb
      format.json {
        render :response => {:format => format}
      }
     end 
end
```

The problem is I do get the 'success' message so apparently there are no routing issues, but I can't see that variable being displayed in the view :

```
<%- flash.each do |key, msg| -%>
  <div id="<%= key %>">
  <p>flash <%= msg %></p>
  <%- end -%>
```

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: Why are you sending `chosenFormat` and then getting it back again without change?

Comment: If you want to see the value returned by the controller, you should change your 'success' function to update your HTML with the new value. you are returning a JSON object, which won't modify the html document itself

Comment: I basically want to get that value passed in to my Controller. Within that controller, then , I can re-Do some work (write a file by running an external script,...)
And that value which I want to send to the controller will eventually be a textfield with a concatenation of multiple dropdown selections.
I'm happy to send me skype if you think I'm too much out of it (and therefore complicating things ... ) =)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the form of the data you send, because like you did not set the type of the message body (contentType) that you sent this he takes the standard just change your code

```
data: "chosenformat=" + "myvalue",
```

Or change the type of the body of the message being that the default is:

```
 contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
```

Comment: data: "chosenformat=" + "myvalue" gives me error 500 on the server , and  contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' doens't make any difference. Thanks for the suggestions though :)
I tend to think that : 
- either it has to me formated properly before sending (xml for eg.)
- or I don't handle the response on the controller side as I should

Answer (score 0):

If you get any JSON response it means that the problem is with the action in your controller.

The problem I see is that:

You assign: `format = params[:chosenformat]` which is ok,

then you set `flash[:format] = "chosen format: " + params[:chosenformat].to_s()` which is also OK,

then you check if format variable is present: `if !(format.nil?)`

BUT! Later you use again `format` variable inside `respond_to` block. But this variable changed its content. Inside the block you don't have `params[:chosenformat]` anymore! 
Instead of this you have current request data.

To fix the problem change variable's name. 
Let me refactor your code a bit:

```
chosen_format = params[:chosenformat]
flash[:format] = "chosen format: #{chosen_format}"

if chosen_format.present?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {
      render json: { format: chosen_format }
    }
  end 
end
```

You will have now your format in json response and if you render html it will be in `flash` variable

Comment: Thanks palinium for that helpful comment :)
it still doesnt work.. quick question : Do I have to reload the page to get my value displayed ? Saying this because here I'm call the Ajax by clicking on my button :
  `<td> <%= button_tag 'Call AJAX' , :class => "button_to" , :id => "completed" , :remote => true %> </td>`
and by url is : ` url: '.'` (see above for full ajax settings)
So maybe it has to reload the page to display it.
cheers